# Observable with Time interval not displaying results on subscribe

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to add a time interval to this Observable sequence( That is produce an integer sequence at a specific timespan) but it seems not to be working. When i remove the time, then it works time. Am i applying the timer wrongly?

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Take(4);
var nums = Observable.Range(1,1200).Where(a => a % 2 == 0);
var sourcenumbs = timer.SelectMany(nums);


var results = sourcenumbs.Subscribe(
              x => Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}",x),
              ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}",ex.Message),
              () => Console.WriteLine("OnComplete")
);
```

This code displays no output, Does it get Dispose before it reaches the Subscribe?

But if i had a forloop with a timer in it then it works. Why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.9));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add a time interval to this Observable sequence". What is output you are expecting? How is the for loop even related to the observable sequence?

Comment: @Euphoric I want the even numbers from 1, 1200 every 2 seconds, without the `Observable.Interval` it was working fine but i wanted to add a timer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Execute();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async void Execute()
{
    var intervals = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).StartWith(0);
    var evenNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1200).Where(a => a % 2 == 0);

    var evenNumbersAtIntervals = intervals.Zip(evenNumbers, (_, num) => num);

    try
    {
        await evenNumbersAtIntervals.ForEachAsync(
            x => Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", x)
        );

        Console.WriteLine("Complete");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception " + e);
    }
}
```

Take note that numbers are `Enumerable` and not `Observable`.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't display anything in the console.

Comment: @SeekAddo You have to stop console from closing, as the code runs asynchronously. Simplest way is to Console.ReadKey(). See my edit.

Comment: you were write. I am using Rider so the console doesn't close like in visual sutdio, but with the Console.ReadKey() it helped.

Comment: What about using `await` on the Subscriber, or the only way is to use the Console.ReadKey. I mean what if is in a real application and it has to send the output to another data.

Comment: @SeekAddo If you want to await completion of the sequence, you should use `ForEachAsync` instead of `Subsribe`. See edit.